# Software to Trim a Video into Multiple Files

Tags: video-editor, editing, software-recommendation, gopro

I am coming from the good old Times from GoPro Studios(discontinued),

Go Pro Studio had a feature I really loved:
To Precut your Videos into Multiple Parts and Naming them Seperatly.
Because Having Hour Long Files on your System is quite a Wastage of Space.
Also, the Ability to go Back and find All Clips Already Trimed and Named was Really Helpful.

Now I'm looking for an Alternative that can:

- Trim one Video into Multiple Files (ideally with a single Watch true
  Selecting Parts with Shortcut I/O without the need to Stop Every Time
  to Export it Manually)
- The Ability to Name the Trimmed Videos
- No or little Quality Loss
- It Should be Free to Use (No Watermark etc...)
- Optional Export Queue to do the Time Heavy Stuff while I do something else...

What are you using for Cutting down your Videos?

What I already looked tried but couldn't find the Feature I was looking for:

- Avidemux
- Hit Film Express
- Quick
- Bandicam (Would be quite Okay but quite Expensive)
- Shotcut

If I missed a way to do it in the one Above feel free to point me to it.
Thanks for your Help!

Comment: I believe I had similar needs and found the software for that. Please see the answer I posted to my question:
https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/32903/setting-points-and-doing-a-quick-snip-dynamically-playing-the-video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this software is what you're looking for
https://mifi.github.io/lossless-cut

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thank you Sir you will Save me a lot of time on the next Video Projekts

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm looking for an Alternative that can:

> Trim one Video into Multiple Files (ideally with a single Watch true Selecting Parts with Shortcut I/O without the need to Stop Every Time to Export it Manually)

In the light of not fully understand the "a single Watch true Selecting Parts with Shortcut I/O", my suggestion would simply happens on ffmpeg, i.e
*ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss <start-time> -t <duration> part1.mp4*

> The Ability to Name the Trimmed Videos

The ffmpeg handles it nicely

> No or little Quality Loss

You may consider the option **-codec:v** option or [more options](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-Options)

> It Should be Free to Use (No Watermark etc...)

FFMPEG is free.

> Optional Export Queue to do the Time Heavy Stuff while I do something else...

scripting could help

Comment: Firstly Thanks for your time, it's well appreciated.
FFMPEG seems like a good solution as it is a command-line tool, but it would need my Time to create a Visual Editor for it. I may look into it into the future but as of right now I don't have the Spare Time to do it.

What I meant with Watch true was the Ability to just watch the Video and mark important Stuff with Shortcut I (Start of cutout Part) -> O (End of Part)

If in two weeks nobody else Answer I will mark your Answer as the Accepted one!
Thanks for the suggestion it is well Appreciated.